# change profile default (custom field)

Tags: profile, default-settings

I have an [application form](https://onw.yobc.org/application/) for students wishing to sign up for an audition. Our student records contain a custom "standing" field to indicate whether they are active (current students), inactive (past students/alumni), or applicants. This field does not appear in the application form, however when the form is submitted the records default to "active." I must have set it up when I created the profile, but can no longer remember or find where to change it. Any help on how I can change the profile to default to "applicant" on this form?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like a custom field with specific options (either a select field, checkbox or radio button). If you go to Administer>Custom Data and Screens>Custom Fields, find the field group and field then click Edit Multiple Choice options. See if the option for "active" is marked as default. Edit the option and uncheck the default option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, concur that if there is a default value being loaded in a Profile, then it will be coming from the Custom Field, rather than a setting in the Profile Field itself.